# How does the compose (*) function work in Ruby (from The Ruby Programming Language)?

Tags: ruby, functional-programming

Excerpt The Ruby Programming Language:

```
module Functional
  def compose(f)
    if self.respond_to?(:arity) && self.arity == 1
      lambda {|*args| self[f[*args]] }
    else
      lambda {|*args| self[*f[*args]] }
    end
  end
  alias * compose
end

class Proc; include Functional; end
class Method; include Functional; end

f = lambda {|x| x * 2 }
g = lambda {|x, y| x * y}
(f*g)[2, 3] # => 12
```

What is the difference between f and *f in the if/else clause?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `*` either collects all the items into an array, or explodes an array into individual elements--depending on the context.

If `args = [1, 2, 3]`, then:

- `f[args]` is equivalent to `f[ [1, 2, 3] ] #There is one argument: an array.`
- `f[*args]` is equivalent to `f[1, 2, 3]    #There are three arguments.`

If `f[*args]` returns `[4, 5, 6]`, then:

- `self[f[*args]]` is equivalent to `self[ [4, 5, 6] ] #self is called with 1 arg.`
- `self[*f[*args]]` is equivalent to `self[4, 5, 6]    #self is called with 3 args.`

An example of `*` being used to collect items into an Array is:

- `lambda {|*args| ....}`

You can call that function with any number of arguments, and all the arguments will be collected into an array and assigned to the parameter variable `args`.

Answer (score 0):

`*` (also known as splat) allows you to call a method with an array of arguments rather than passing the values individually. If you left off the splat then ruby would just pass a single value (that happens to be an array). This unary `*` is not the `*` operation that this code defines as an alias of `compose`

In the if branch `self` has an arity of 1, then `f` should be returning a single value and so there is no need for the splat.

In the else branch `self` takes more than one argument, it follows that `f` should return an array of values, and the splat is used to call `self` with those arguments.

Comment: **then f should be returning a single value** All functions and methods return a single value.  The `*` is omitted so that if f returns an array of arguments, they are all passed as one argument to self(because self only accepts one argument).

Comment: **In the else branch, .... it follows that f should return an array of values**  There are no restrictions on what f can return.  If f returns a value like 10, then the `*` will do nothing, and 10 will be assigned to self's first parameter variable.

Comment: You'd have to use `proc` rather than `lambda` to get the relaxed argument counting you describe ( you'll get away with the case when self has arity 1 depending on computation self performs). As it stands if the f in the example had 2 arguments then you'd get argument error when computing `(f*g)[2, 3]`